Spring boot + oracle + weblogic error " javax.naming.NoInitialContextException" How to solve?
application.properties
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:/comp/env/jdbc/myDemoDs
spring.jndi.properties.java.naming.factory.initial=weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory
spring.jndi.properties.java.naming.provider.url=t3://localhost:7001
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

I have use above configuration for JNDI but getting error..
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial

You need to provide those as system properties. I.e. add something like System.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory"). To your main method before the SpringApplication.run.

Hi Deinum, Thank you for your perfect guidance.
I have added system properties and weblogic.jar to my application but got error...
"java.lang.Error: factory already defined"

If you already added the jar you shouldn't need those properties I think. There already part of the weblogic.jar. Try without setting them. AFAIK the spring.jndi properties don't do or add anything.

If I don't add weblogic.jar then error occur java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory and if I don't add System.properties then error  Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException and if I add both then error  "java.lang.Error: factory already defined. how to solve?

You don't need to specify the factory only java.naming.provider.url. You obviously will need the jar as that contains the JNDI classes to connect to weblogic.

I have remove JNDI config in application.properties and below code added in Main application class.
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { JmxAutoConfiguration.class})

and
@Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        try {
            System.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
            InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
            // Use the full JNDI name including the application and module names
            return (DataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/ekpDataSource");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to lookup DataSource", e);
        }
    }


    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

don't forgot to add external (weblogic.jar) jar in yourproject.
you find weblogic.jar file to this path {WebLogic_Home}/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.jar
